# Move a pair into vector

Tags: c++, c++11, move, std-pair

I have this function template:

```
template<typename Collection, typename T>
void insertColElement(Collection col, const T& element, std::true_type)
{
    col.insert(col.end(), std::move(element));
}
```

It is called if T is move-constructable. Now I want to call this function with Collection = `std::vector<..>` and T = `std::pair<std::unique_ptr<..>, bool>`, but the compiler complains about the deleted copy constructor of unique_ptr and pair. I already tried to use emplace and move first and second seperately, but the compiler still wants to call the copy constructor.

Edit:

Here are all relevant code snippets:

```
template<typename Collection, typename T>
void insertColElement(Collection col, T&& element, std::true_type)
{
    col.insert(col.end(), std::forward<T>(element));
}



template<typename Collection, typename T>
void insertColElement(Collection col, T& element, std::false_type)
{
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value,
        "Serialization: Collection type is neither copy nor move constructable");

    col.insert(col.end(), element);
}


template<typename Archive, typename Collection>
inline void loadCollection(Archive& ar, Collection& col)
{
    int size;
    ar >> size;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        typename Collection::value_type element;
        ar >> element;

        insertColElement(col, std::move(element), 
            typename std::is_move_constructible<typename Collection::value_type>::type());
    }
}
```

These functions are part of a small serialization module I am working at. `loadCollection` is used to load a container from an Archiv. The call that causes the issues looks like this:

```
IStreamArchive a(filestream);
std::vector<std::pair<std::unique_ptr<Scope>, bool>> vec;
a << vec;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't move-from something that is const, so you end up with the copy constructor even though you wrote `move()` (since `move` is just a cast, you cast element to a `const T&&`. There is no `const T&&` constructor, and the `T&&` constructor doesn't match, so the next best match is the `const T&` constructor). That's the problem.

You should instead write the following:

```
template<typename Collection, typename T>
void insertColElement(Collection& col, T&& element, std::true_type)
{
    col.insert(col.end(), std::forward<T>(element));
}
```

Comment: I still get these compiler errors. I call the function like this: `typename Collection::value_type element; insertColElement(col, std::move(element),  typename std::is_move_constructible<typename Collection::value_type>::type());` I am not that familiar with move semantics yet, so I don't know if std::move is at the right place.

Comment: @JonasThiele Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: @JonasThiele You're passing the collection by value - and you can't copy a container of noncopyable stuff. I realize I forgot the `&` in my answer as well. Note that also this is unnecessary, as you can just do `col.push_back(std::move(element));` directly.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't notice that, thanks for pointing out that mistake.